# Count until condition is true

Tags: r, if-statement, count, counter

Count how many time will make a sample of two numbers from a vector of 'x <- c(2,4,5,6,8,3)' with replacement before the two numbers add up to '11'. Stop loop as soon as it obtained two numbers exactly equal to 11 and then count how many samples was selected before the stop?

```
 x <- c(2,4,5,6,8,3)
 y <- c()
 repeat{y <- c(y, sample(x[!x %in% y], 1) )
if( sum(v2) == 11 )
break
 }
```

I am interested in how many count of sample of two that sum up to did not sum up to 11 before the first samples that did sum up to 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
x <- c(2,4,5,6,8,3)
y <- c()
i<-0
while(sum(y)!=11)
{
  y <- sample(x[!x %in% y], 2)
  i<-i+1
}
i
```

In the while loop you have the sample extracted and a counter, looping until the sum is 11.
In `i` you will have the number of loop needed to have a couple with sum equal to 11.